# How to write a test case for product sum question

Tags: arrays, go, interface

I am trying to write a test case in my main function for the following code that is used to find the product and sum of a nested array:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SpecialArray []interface{}

func ProductSum(array SpecialArray) int {
        return helper(array, 1)
}

func helper(array SpecialArray, multiplier int) int {
        sum := 0
        for _, el := range array {
                if cast, ok := el.(SpecialArray); ok {
                        sum += helper(cast, multiplier + 1)
                } else if cast, ok := el.(int); ok {
                        sum += cast
                }
        }
        return sum * multiplier

}
```

Given a nested array with a mix of ints and arrays, the above code should return the sum of all elements. Elements within a nested array will be summed then multiplied by their depth, i.e.,

[1, [2, 3], 2] = 1 + 2(2+3) + 2 = 13

I am having trouble understanding the SpecialArray []interface{} type. My first attempt was to simply define a nested slice in my main function as follows:

```
func main() {
        SpecialArray := [][]int{1, {2, 3}, 2}
        result := ProductSum(SpecialArray)
        fmt.Println(result)
}
```

But this is not working. I'm assuming I need to initalize my SpecialArray interface with values and pass that to my ProductSum function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close but did not quite get the array literal syntax right:

```
func main() {
    special := SpecialArray{1, SpecialArray{2, 3}, 2}
    result := ProductSum(special)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Also your `helper` function is fine as is but you might consider using a type switch:

```
func helper(array SpecialArray, multiplier int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range array {
        switch v := v.(type) {
        case int:
            sum += v
        case SpecialArray:
            sum += helper(v, multiplier+1)
        default:
            log.Fatalf("Unknown type: %T", v)
        }
    }
    return sum * multiplier
}
```

BTW the `SpecialArray` type is a slice not an array.